# c++ how to return object of current classes type (inheritance)

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'd like to do something like this:

```
class A{
public:
    A(int i);

    static A* createWithSpecialCalculation(int a, int b, int c){
      // ...complex calculation here...
      return new A(result_of_calculation);
    }
};

class B:A{
public:
    float m_additionalMember;
};
```

now I want to be able to call

```
B* myB = B::createWithSpecialCalculation(1,2,3);
```

Is this possible somehow?
if so, how?

Comment: If I had a pound for every time I saw a class definition on Stack Overflow without the terminating `;`...

Comment: but i'd like to be able to call that function not only on B, but also on A

Comment: @Lightness: I always forget those in my code and then wonder half an hour about the strange compiler errors :)

Comment: so i need to have the same code in both, A and B? doesn't look nice

Comment: It won't be the same code. One creates a `B`, while the other creates a `A`. If the constructor parameters will always be the same, consider a free template function: `template <typename T> T* createOne(int a, int b, int c) { int x = complexCalculation(a,b,c); return new T(x); }`

Comment: There is no need for your factory methods to be class member at all, as far as I can see.

Comment: exactly something like this i look for, except that i don't want to have to type B::createOne<B>(1,2,3) - can't it take the generic argument somehow automatically as the current Type?

Comment: @Mat: Automatically how? By reading your mind?

Comment: no i meant, by refering to the own class (A::... should refere to A, B::... should refere to B) - but i got it working now with templates :)

Answer (score 1):

How about:
Just change the definition of `createWithSpecialCalculation` in A slightly.

```
template<typename T>
static T* createWithSpecialCalculation(int a, int b, int c){
  // ...complex calculation here...
  return new T(result_of_calculation);
}
```

Then you can go:

```
B* myB = A::createWithSpecialCalculation<B>(1,2,3);
```

Comment: ohai :D Why make it a member at all, though?

Comment: ah - that's great! i made the templated function private and added untemplated public versions that call the templated version with the appropriate Typename. works =) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance may not be appropriate here.

Instead, consider a free template function:

```
template <typename T>
T* createOne(int a, int b, int c) {
   int x = complexCalculation(a,b,c);
   return new T(x);
}
```

That is, if the argument(s) to the constructor will be the same no matter the type `A` or `B`; from your desire to avoid *any* code duplication, it sounds like that's already helpfully the case.

```
A* myA = createOne<A>(1,2,3);
B* myB = createOne<B>(1,2,3);
```

Consider `shared_ptr<>` rather than these raw pointers, though.